# Positioning of pie chart data labels

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

Is it possible to dynamically position data lables for a SSRS/PowerBI Report Builder pie chart?
My goal is to have any slice >= 20% to be outside and the rest to be inside.

I have tried this expression:
=IIf(Fields!Class.Value >= .20, "Inside", "Outside")
but all data labels are being placed inside the chart.